# $http returning 404 eror in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cordova, http-status-code-404

I am having an error with a mobile app built with AngularJS and Ionic Framework on Cordova / PhoneGap.  I have released a build to some users to test and only a few users are telling me that their username and passwords aren't authenticating.  I can't replicate the error since it only seems to be with these few individuals with problems.

My code is below.  It connects to one of our servers and checks the username and password. It will return "1" if username/pass is valid or "0" if invalid with JSONP format.  If the request fails, then the $http request has an error handler that will print out the error code.  I added an alert to pop up the status for $http errors and the user told me they got a 404 error. AngularJS with 1.3.0 and 1.2.17 had the same issues.

I am confused as to why some users might have problems. I suspect it might be CORS, but I am using JSONP and most people are authenticating without any problems. My config.xml is also set to  `<access origin="*" />`

```
$scope.attemptLogin = function() {
  var reqUrl = "https://MYSERVER.com/auth.php?";

  //If input has email, strip it out
  var newUser = ($scope.credentials.username).toLowerCase();
  var domainMatch = newUser.match(/@MYSERVER.com/g);
  $scope.credentials.username = newUser.replace(domainMatch, '');

  //Authenticate the username and password
  $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: reqUrl + "other_auth_code_stuff" + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"

  }).success(function(data, status) {

    //Username and password valid
    if (data == 1) {

          //User is authenticated
      AuthService.setUserAuthenticated(true);
      console.log("Login successful");

      //Redirect the state since we're successful
      $state.go('app.dashboard');
    }
    //Username and password invalid
    else {

        //User is not authenticated
        AuthService.setUserAuthenticated(false);
        alertPass(); //Popup to tell user that user/pw is wrong
        console.log("Username/Password incorrect");
    }

  }).error(function(data, status) {
     AuthService.setUserAuthenticated(false);

      alert(status); //RETURNING 404
      alertError();
      console.log("Authentication failure");
  });
```

};

Comment: have you set up any logging on server to see what data, headers , cookies etc are sent when logins fail?

Comment: No I haven't yet. My access to the server is limited, so I'll be contacting one of the co-workers post-weekend to see if he could check those out.